# How to put column grids in a Raw Data File

Tags: sas

here is a raw data file that I created using the program below.
I would like to know how to put the column grids (I am not sure what it is called so excuse me for using this name if incorrect)

that looks like

----|---10----|---20---

?

I am guessing that there should be an option that I can use but I could not find one in my text book (the text book shows as if the column grids are there by default)
I appreciate your help.

```
data a;
input name$ id age;
cards;
Ruth 39 11
Jose 32 22
Sue 30 33
John 40 44
;
run;

data _null_;
set a;
file 'C:\Users\stardust\Desktop\employee';
put name 1-4 id 6-7 age 9-10;
run;
```

Comment: Don't forget that adding any content to a data file that is not data must be filtered out when read back in.  If you are reviewing a data file it may be better to use a tool that shows a ruler, rather than changing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the "----|---10----|---20---" is just used as a teaching tool and is not an option or something that's done in practice.

In any case here's how you would do it. You could use the Macro system and macro this out, but I hard coded it.

```
data a;
input name$ id age;
cards;
Ruth 39 11
Jose 32 22
Sue 30 33
John 40 44
;
run;

data _null_;
set a;
file 'C:\Users\stardust\Desktop\employee';
If _N_ = 1 then do;
Put "----|---10----|---20---";
end;
put name 1-4 id 6-7 age 9-10;
run;
```

Good luck in your class.

Comment: Thank you!  This is the closest thing to what I wanted to do and will work for now.
Can you explain to me what the _ N _ is?  I know that since it is in a IF =1 THEN DO END statement it will be executed no matter what.

Comment: _ N _ is a variable that is automatically made at the start of a data step. It's an internal counter of the number if times the date step has looped. Often it's used as a row counter.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for a way to examine your file?

Try using the LIST statement.

```
data _null_;
  infile 'C:\Users\stardust\Desktop\employee';
  input;
  list;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to have the raw data file to have the Ruler in it so that I can read it easily.

Answer (score 1):

A `COLS` line is known as a *ruler* line in other editors.  This line is a user interface feature that is not kept during *save* or *submit* actions.  As a UI feature you can not even copy the line into the clipboard buffer.

Add a comment line to your source that contains the ruler line.

```
data a;
input name$ id age;
* 3456789.123456789.1234567890.123456789.123456789. ;
cards;
Ruth 39 11
Jose 32 22
Sue 30 33
John 40 44
;
run;
```

Other rulers as source code comments

```
/* 456789.123456789.1234567890.123456789.123456789. */
%* 456789.123456789.1234567890.123456789.123456789. ;
* --|----10---|----20---|----30---|----40---|----50---| ;
%* -|----10---|----20---|----30---|----40---|----50---| ;
/*--|----10---|----20---|----30---|----40---|----50---| */
```

The comment can not be part of `datalines` interior.

In the *enhanced editor* you can use menu `Tools / Add abbreviation` to configure a phrase, that when typed, raises an IntelliSense style popup containing the ruler to be inserted.